# What should the HTTP Status Code of a Degraded Health Check Be?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-503, health-monitoring, kubernetes-health-check

I have a health check endpoint at `/status` that returns the following status codes and response bodies:

- Healthy - `200 OK`
- Degraded - `?`
- Unhealthy - `503 Service Unnavailable`

What should the HTTP status code be for a degraded response be? A 'degraded' check is used for checks that [did succeed but are slow or unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027674/whats-the-difference-between-unhealthy-vs-degraded-net-health-check-status). What HTTP status code makes the most sense?

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense. You need to decide what HTTP `GET` of `/status` should do

Comment: Exactly, so what should I decide? What HTTP status code makes the most sense?

Comment: You may decide and document that such a `GET` of `/status` returns some [JSON](http://json.org/) data. What is the format and the interpretation of that data is your decision

Comment: What do you believe your choices to be? If it's working we use 200 and return additional information if necessary. Really, it's up to you.

Comment: Yes I get that it's up to me. I'm here for guidance, you know...what StackOverflow is here for. I think my choices are 200, 503, 202 Accepted or something else.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed return a custom code withing the 2xx Success range that is not already taken withing the known/common codes. Similar to some of the [unofficial codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) not supported by any standard. For example `218 This is fine (Apache Web Server)`

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed also found this https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-inadarei-api-health-check-00

Comment: @Nkosi That is a really nice find. Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed hoping you check the more [recent version](https://inadarei.github.io/rfc-healthcheck/) They also suggested `In case of the “warn” status, endpoints MUST return HTTP status in the 2xx-3xx range, and additional information SHOULD be provided, utilizing optional fields of the response.` where `warn` status is `healthy, with some concerns`, which I believe aligns closely to you mode.

Comment: The spec is not as prescriptive as I'd have hoped but you should definately add that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: It also provided some insight about one of your other question about dependencies on other components/microservices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most suitable HTTP status code for a "Degraded" status response from a health endpoint is nothing other than `200 OK`.

I say this because I can't find any better code in the official [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) maintained by IANA, pointed to by [[RFC7231] HTTP/1.1: Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.2). Unofficial codes should be avoided, because they only make your API more difficult to understand.

You should design your APIs so that they become easy to use. Resource names, HTTP verbs, status codes, etc. should be more or less self-explanatory, so that people who already know "the REST language" can immediately understand how to use your API without having to decipher vague names or unusual status codes. Which brings me to the next part of my answer...

**Other comments on your design**

The most natural way to interpret a `5xx` response to any request is that the operation in question failed.

So a `503 Service Unavailable` response to a `GET /status` request means that *the status checking operation itself* failed. Such a response would only be useful if we can be certain that `/status` is a *health endoint*, as pointed out in the [API Health Check draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-inadarei-api-health-check-02) referred to in Nkosi's answer:

> A health endpoint is only meaningful in the context of the component
> it indicates the health of.  It has no other meaning or purpose.  As
> such, its health is a conduit to the health of the component.
> Clients SHOULD assume that the HTTP response code returned by the
> health endpoint is applicable to the entire component (e.g. a larger
> API or a microservice).

But with a URL path of just `/status`, it is not completely obvious that this really *is* a health endpoint. From looking at the URL, we only know that it returns information about the status of something, but we can't really be sure what that "something" is.

Since you're also telling us that yes, it is in fact a health endpoint, I must suggest that you change the name to `health`. I would also suggest placing it under some base path, e.g. `/things/health`, to make it more clear which component it indicates the health of.

If, on the other hand, `/status` was actually a resource of it own, i.e. something that represents the status of some *other* component/thing (like its name currently suggests), then `200 OK` is the only reasonable status for successful invocations, even if the thing that it indicates the status of is "Unhealthy". In that case, a `5xx` would mean that no status could be obtained, and details in the response payload would be assumed to be related to a failure in the `/status` service itself.

So be careful with how you name things and what status codes you use!

Answer (score 3):

Consider returning a custom code within the *2xx Success* range that is not already taken within the known/common status codes. Similar to some of the [unofficial codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) not supported by any standard.

For example `218 This is fine (Apache Web Server)`

> Used as a catch-all error condition for allowing response bodies to flow through Apache when ProxyErrorOverride is enabled. When ProxyErrorOverride is enabled in Apache, response bodies that contain a status code of 4xx or 5xx are automatically discarded by Apache in favor of a generic response or a custom response specified by the ErrorDocument directive

After doing some research I came across a draft

[Health Check Response Format for HTTP APIs: draft-inadarei-api-health-check-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-inadarei-api-health-check-02)

Where they also made similar suggestions

> In case of the “warn” status, endpoints MUST return HTTP status in the 2xx-3xx range, and additional information SHOULD be provided, utilizing optional fields of the response.

where the `warn` status in the draft is `healthy, with some concerns`, which I believe aligns closely to your desired model.

While not definitive, I believe it provides some ideas to help with the eventual design.

Comment: I contacted the author of the draft over Twitter (See https://twitter.com/RehanSaeedUK/status/1081121474667253760?s=20). His response was basically to refer to the HTTP RFC (which isn't much help) and avoid unofficial status codes. While not a complete answer, your input is valuable, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would be wary of splitting hairs like this on a healthcheck on the upstream server side. The service providing the healthcheck should be lightly (and concurrently) testing all its upstream dependencies based on its own set of policies or rules - request timeouts, connection failures and so on. In reality the healthcheck either works or it doesn't and the application shouldn't really need to be keeping track of the results of the healthcheck (other than capturing metrics about what happened). IMHO a stateful healthcheck is a recipe for disaster.

I typically use the following interface for application healthchecks:

`204 - No Content, everything is working within tolerences`

`500 - Something failed, and here's some details in the response about what went wrong`

Where it gets tricky depends on your architecture. You may have a VIP or reverse proxy that is interpreting this response and deciding if a given node is healthy or not, in which case it's going to either route the request to a healthy node or return the `503 Service Unavailable`. This decision is going to made on some policy basis - x healthcheck requests failed over a y time period across z upstream services.

If you use a mesh then everyone can feed data back to the service registry to keep the health state up to date and it can be based on actual service calls rather than a healthcheck.

The client is perfectly placed to make a decision based on the health of services it depends on as they can keep track of the various responses from the service. Circuit breakers are an excellent way to handle that and can do it continuously on actual requests rather than just on the healthcheck. Circuit breaker libraries (such as [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j)) will do this for you at the cost of setting up some policies about how many failed/slow requests constitute a bad service. Service Registrys like the netflix eureka can help with the discovery and ongoing monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to the status code of a liveness/healthcheck endpoint of a service - to  distinguish from *200 OK* a **[203](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.4)** likely seems applicable and in line with:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-inadarei-api-health-check/
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.5 despite being deprecated `Warning: 199`-header MAY carry details
- align `max-age` with `livenessProbe.periodSeconds`

```
HTTP/1.1 203 Non-Authoritative Information
Warning: 199 - "FooBar Warning Details"
Content-Type: application/health+json
Cache-Control: max-age=10
Connection: close

{"status": "warn"}
```